# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_28 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 50, 21, 8]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

**Input dimensions**:

```
train_ohe :(95036, 50, 21)
y_train :(95036,)
val_ohe :(9911, 50, 21)
y_val :(9911,)
```

**Model** :

```
x_input = Input(shape=(50,))
emb = Embedding(21, 8, input_length=50)(x_input)
bi_rnn = LSTM(50, input_shape=(50,20,50), return_sequences=False)(emb)
x = Dropout(0.3)(bi_rnn)
x_output = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model1 = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=x_output)
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

history1 = model1.fit(
    train_ohe, y_train,
    epochs=1, batch_size=256,validation_data=(val_ohe, y_val),callbacks=[es]
    )
```

**Note**

```
Vocab size=20, input_length=50
```

I tried changing return_sequences for True/False and also tried dimensions of **LSTM** layer from `(50, 20)/(50,20,50)` but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are feeding one-hot vectors to Embedding layer. You should feed sequences of integers. Shape should be (95036, 50).

If you really need to feed one-hot vectors - you have to convert one-hot to integer to feed them into Embedding layer. Try something like that:

```
x_input = Input(shape=(50, 21))
x = tf.argmax(x_input, axis=-1)
emb = Embedding(21, 8, input_length=50)(x)
```

Comment: my input is protein sequences, I wanted to capture the position/order of characters in sequence. I thought feeding integer encoded sequences may not help much as it will has values(model could give weightage to values) eg: integer encoded seq - [ 2, 7, 11, 4, 4, 2, 10, 6, 6, 3, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5].

Comment: why do you think so ? What is a difference between feeding [1, 0, 1] and [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]] ? Why do you think the order is lost in the first and is saved in the second ?

Comment: It's not about the order, it's also about the weightage given to values in the sequence as integer encoded sequence has values, whereas the one-hot representation has 0 & 1, so I wanted to feed one-hot vectors.

Comment: @veenapulicherla still don't understand, but I updated the answer so that you can feed one hot vectors

Comment: You are correct, I didn't look at it clearly, I now removed the embedding layer, feeding one hot vector to the LSTM. Thanks,  your answer helped.